# Join two collection and perform aggregate and group by in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I have below two collection and I wanted to see the number of task of a project in single output. i.e One project can contain many tasks. So how do I retrieve total project details along with number of task of each project.

I have tried using lookup to join but It gives the matching tasks as a whole object in the output but not getting the number of tasks as single value.

Thanks in advance for the help.!

```
Project collection:
{ "title":"Project1", "status":"not completed"}
{ "title":"Project2", "status":"completed"}

Task collection:
{ "projectTitle":"Project1", "task":"Task1"}
{ "projectTitle":"Project1", "task":"Task2"}

Expected Output:
[
    { "title":"Project1", "status":"not completed", "noOfTask":2},
    { "title":"Project2", "status":"completed", "noOfTask":0}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `mongodb aggregation pipeline` with `$lookup` and `$project` stage to achieve this.

You were going on the right path with doing the `lookup` in `task` collection. You just needed to add one more `$project` stage. The idea is to project `noOfTasks` as the `size of array` returned in `$lookup` stage.

Try this :

```
db.projects.aggregate([{
    $lookup : {
        from : "tasks",//name of your task collection
        localField : "title",
        foreignTitle : "projectTitle",
        as : "tasks"
    }
},{
    $project : {
        title : "$title",
        status : "$status",
        nofTask : {$size : "$tasks"}
    }
}])
```

Read about [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for quick response. $size is what I was missing I think. You are right about the pipeline. And I found great video about aggregation and sharing it. Hope this help for our friends
https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/aggregation-framework-0

Comment: I just tried in my system and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! im really glad i could help